# How to change inflexible leading in indesign?

Tags: adobe-indesign, white-space

I've been trying to change the space between the lines of the paragraph in this text. I've tried using the leading, space before, and space after buttons. All had the same result.

[image: Leading]

As you can see the change between 13pt and 12 pt is significant. I had absolutely nothing happening when I went up from 1 to 12. Only between 12 and 13 there is this large jump. The same happens between 13 and 24. No change until I hit 25 where there is again a large jump. I also have the large jump between 0 and 1.

For this particular text both choices are not that bad. However, I want the same spacing for the entire page. And in this image the distance really makes a difference to the look I'm going for.

[image: Leading2]
The 13 is way too far apart and the 12 is way too close together.
What I want is to have the linespace somewhere between the 12 and 13. Not too close together but not too far apart.

Am I doing something wrong? Or is there something wrong with my Indesign?
How can I achieve what I want?

Comment: I think you might have snap to grid switched on - google it and check your settings - even tell us what you found out

Comment: Snap to grid does not affect body copy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you are probably using *align to baseline grid* with the default increments of 12 points. Thus, your leading will automatically round up to multiples of 12, explaining the various jumps.

- Select the problematic text frame and look for this icon in the
  paragraph panel. The left icon disables *align to baseline grid*,
  whereas the right icon forces alignment.

[image]

---

Since you mention you do want to use consistent leading...

- You may also keep *align to baseline grid* enabled, and change the
  settings of the baseline grid *Increment Every* instead in Edit >
  Preferences > Grids (Windows) or InDesign > Preferences > Grids (Mac
  OS). This window sets up a baseline grid that applies for a whole document.

  [image]

---

- In addition, you may wish to use a baseline grid for an isolated text
  frame. In this case, you would select the target text frame, and look
  for the 2nd tab in its properties. There you can change the
  *Increment Every* for this single text frame.

[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: You are erroneously mixing the functionalities, what is changed from the icon to the changes to be made from preferences or from the text properties window are three different things: adjust the selected text to the grid, define the document grid options  and define a custom text frame grid.

Comment: @Danielillo Not mixing functionalities. OP may need to be aware of these 3 places in order to fix the problem. Maybe screenshots will clear up things when I have time to add them in an hour.

Comment: You don't clarify in your answer what each of these three options do, which can lead to confusion: there's an icon to do what? In the menu preferences you change what? Going to the text frame options panel affects what? I think your answer for someone who doesn't know this Indesign's features is quite confusing and I don't think this will be solved with just some screenshots.

Comment: Listen, feel free to downvote. I wrote this answer on mobile so I wasn't even sure on the terms used. I'll edit later with explained screenshots. You are free to write a better answer if you want. My objective was to give some timely leads to OP without answering in a comment.

Comment: Actually I didn't write an answer for that reason, it's not as simple as it looks, there are many things involved, about design, layout and InDesign features. That's why I think your answer confuses even more.

Comment: @Emillie While I did at first find your answer confusing, I played around a litle till I got it. Switching the align to baseline grid icon in the paragraph panel did get the jumping to stop. However, the problem was for the entire document, so I ended up changing the increment every to 1pt instead of 12. Thanks for the screenshots, that really helped clear things up.

Comment: @Bianca Glad it was helpful! Baseline grids are a bit finicky, and more worth the trouble when designing multi-panel or multi-page layout.

Comment: @Bianca Setting the baseline grid to 1pt kind of defeats the purpose – you’d be better off just disabling the alignment to it instead (most easily done in the paragraph style settings – if all your styles inherit from [Basic Paragraph] you only need to do it once and everything will update accordingly). As Emilie says, the baseline grid is only really something you should worry about if you have multiple panels or pages that need to line up _with each other_, but if you do need that, setting it to 1pt makes it quite useless (and still messes up fractional leadings too).

Comment: Agree with @JanusBahsJacquet! I missed the 1pt part of the comment. I would just disable it altogether.